# Run WAR file in AWS Beanstalk

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, maven, jersey, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I created a Web Server with java and jersey. I also use MAVEN. I am able to run the project from the command line with this command

```
mvn clean verify org.codehaus.cargo:cargo-maven2-plugin:run
```

My problem is that I want to deploy the project in an Amazon aws Elastic Beanstalk as a java application. I have to upload the code there and amazon will execute it with this command

```
java -jar mywar.war
```

If I try to run my project locally with this command, I get this error

```
no main manifest attribute, in project.war
```

So I think that's why the project is not running properly in the Beanstalk. Is it possible to run my project with this java command or I must use the mvn command?

Comment: Deploy your war in a web container like tomcat. war is web archive it is not fr command line.

Comment: This would be easy with [Spring Boot](http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/) which allows you to create war files that can be deployed in a regular web container or started standalone, with exactly the command that you posted above (`java -jar mywar.war`).

Answer (score 1):

Try to open the manifest file in your generated war file, most likely it is missing the Main-Classinformation. A sample of a MANIFEST file containing that is like:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: org.xxx.xxx.
```

You can try to add the Main file information in the maven plugin config under your pom file. Something like this:

```
  <plugin>
    ...

    <configuration>
      <archive>
        <manifest>
          <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
          <mainClass>fully.qualified.MainClass</mainClass>
        </manifest>
      </archive>
    ...
  </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because your maven is using cargo plugin. If you want to run it from the command line like a regular java application you need to start the Jetty or the Tomcat or the whatever you are using in embedded mode. Here is a link describing how to start Jetty from the application.

http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.4.x/embedded-examples.html

Answer (score 0):

Beanstalk seems to offer [Tomcat](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/java-tomcat-platform.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you expect to run your artifact through `java -jar` then check you have `<packaging>jar</packaging>` instead of `<packaging>war</packaging>` in the `pom.xml`.

Also make sure you have declared the main class in the manifest as described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/58004127/1665809.